# Access denied accessing Documents from Records Center Site

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, site-collection, records-center

I am getting 401 access denied errors when I try accessing Records Center Documents from either Drop off Library or Record Library.

The error I get is following

```
{"error":{"code":"-2147024891, System.UnauthorizedAccessException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource."}}}
```

I am using Client Credentials Flow to get the access token (i.e, App Only Token) and my application asks for complete access to all lists for all Site Collections.

Then why this 401 access denied error? I can access the docs from Team Sites, Developer Sites, Project Sites, and Documents Center.

Why do I get it for Records Center then?